# Adding 0.5 to counter in result of a draw?

Tags: c#

I'm making a game and I need to change the code below in order to add 0.5 to the running "playerScore++;" and "computerScore++;" respectively, when the result happens to come out in a draw. So instead of rolling again, as demonstrated below, it will just continue play. I can't figure it out! Will it simply be:

```
playerScore += 0.5;
computerScore += 0.5;
```

Instead of the message box popping up?

I hope that makes sense, sorry! Thanks!

```
 private void button5_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            playerDice = new Dice();
            int playerDiceNo = playerDice.FaceOfDie;
            MessageBox.Show("Your roll: " + playerDiceNo);

            compDice = new Dice();
            int compDiceNo = compDice.FaceOfDie;
            MessageBox.Show("Computers roll: " + compDiceNo);
            if (compDiceNo == playerDiceNo)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Draw - click Roll or Chance");
                button5.Enabled = true;
                button1.Enabled = true;
            }

        }
```

Comment: Did you try what you are proposing?

Comment: You haven't shown the definition for `playerScore`. If it's defined as `int`, then no, this won't work without changing the definition.

Comment: Sorry, it was     public double playerScore = 0;
        public double computerScore = 0;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, the [addition assignment operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/sa7629ew%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) (`+=`) will give you the desired effect. Try this:

```
if (compDiceNo == playerDiceNo)
{
    computerScore += 0.5;
    playerScore += 0.5;
    button5.Enabled = true;
    button1.Enabled = true;
}
```

It's basically shorthand for doing:

```
computerScore = computerScore + 0.5;
playerScore = playerScore + 0.5;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, just needed some confirmation!

Comment: @Bexolo No problems, if this was the correct answer please click the green tick next to it. Welcome to SO!